# How to combine two arrays and repeat one of them until the length of the other?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array I would like to combine.

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want result like this:

```
1 = a
2 = b
3 = c
4 = a
5 = b
6 = c
7 = a
8 = b
```

My current attempt looks like this:

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
    $count = min(count($arr1), count($arr2));
    return array_combine(array_slice($arr1, 0, $count), array_slice($arr2, 0, $count));
}

print_r(array_combine2($arr1,$arr2));
```

But it doesn't produce the expected output as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function combineThatShit($keys, $values){
    $ret = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!isset($values[$i])) $i = 0;
        $ret[$key] = $values[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mZZlv

Comment: awesome. hit the checkmark by my answer if this did it for you.

Comment: Multiple Great answers! All are working but this solution was posted first. So, I am accepting this. Thank you --RizJa --Object-Manipulator

Answer (score 1):

Try the modulus if you know your a2 size.

```
$a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
$a2 = ['a','b','c'];
$a3;

//Hardcoding the modulus value
for ($x = 0; $x < count($a1); $x++) {
    $a3[$x] = $a2[($a1[$x] - 1) % 3];
}

//Dynamic value as per a2 size
for ($x = 0; $x < count($a1); $x++) {
    $a3[$x] = $a2[($a1[$x] - 1) % count($a2)];
}

print_r($a3);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => a [4] => b [5] => c [6] => a [7] => b)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It get two notice 
 `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in /home/**/web/php/somearray.php on line 32
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1 in /home/**/web/php/somearray.php on line 32`

Comment: You may wanna check your array keys. They don't seem to match with the intended one.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I realize that but the question doesn't explicitly state what is required for index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can solve this simple with a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) and just append those two arrays as [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) and one of them as [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php).

Code:

```
<?php

    $arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    $arr2 = ['a','b','c'];
    $result = [];

    $mIt = new MultipleIterator();
    $mIt->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr1));
    $mIt->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr2)));

    foreach($mIt as $v)
        $result[$v[0]] = $v[1];

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [4] => a
    [5] => b
    [6] => c
    [7] => a
    [8] => b
)
```

Comment: This is great too! Thank you